# Static DHCP with Century Link Modem

Tags: dhcp, modem

I'm currently attempting to change my IP address with my modem provided by my ISP (Centurylink). I was told because of the service I have, they use Dynamic IPs with indefinite lease time, and that changing the modem would be the only solution. Unfortunately, they can't just send me the modem, they have to send a technician out, which of course comes with a $100 service fee.

Is there anyway to assign a new IP to the modem without needing a completely new modem?

Comment: If your ISPs DHCP is set up to give infinite leases, and they're not willing to change the DHCP server on their end, then yes, you're stuck with what they said - basically you need a new MAC address on your modem, which generally means a new modem.

Comment: No ISP will use an "indefinite" lease time. With the number of modems that die and how large their footprint is, that would mean manually removing those entries if the modem died. If not maintained, that would start sucking up IPs, and the maintenance would be inane. Furthermore, per RFC 2131, the value is 32 bit and so would last over a century, but not indefinitely (though from their point of view, that is more or less indefinite I suppose). Most lease times are usually between 24 hrs and 1 week. That said, some modem/router combos will let you change the mac address in the webui.

Answer (score 0):

Most ISPs will assign a new external IP address if the MAC address of the first device connected to the modem changes.   Instead of connecting your cable modem to a router, connect it (for approx 1 hour or so) to a laptop, desktop, anything with an Ethernet port.   You might notice that it takes awhile to refresh.  Might want to call your ISP while you are waiting and tell them that you are having network issues and they might try to refresh your connection.

Comment: I did try this. I was told because of the TV service I have, they can not assign a new IP. The only solution available, so I was told, was to get a new modem, however I was being jerked around by support, I really felt that given a different rep, I may have been able to get it changed.

Comment: You actually tried this and it did not work?   How long did you leave it plugged in for?

Comment: I tried leaving the device unplugged over night for ~12 hours, and I tried leaving the device plugged in directly to my computer (by passing the modem). I did not call support at the time it was plugged in, however I did call them and asked them to re-assign an IP to my modem, and they said that they couldn't. I will try plugging in with network issues as you said.